# Find pid of a certain ssh instance

Tags: linux, bash, process, ssh

There can be more than one instance of `ssh` running:

```
$ ps aux | grep ssh
cpn       6098  0.0  0.0  58196  2032 ?        S    10:08   0:01 ssh cz -nNCTR 5433:localhost4:5432
root      6313  0.0  0.0  64072  1168 ?        Ss   12:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      6504  0.0  0.0  97816  3856 ?        Ss   15:48   0:00 sshd: cpn [priv] 
cpn       6508  0.0  0.0  97816  1780 ?        S    15:49   0:00 sshd: cpn@pts/0  
cpn       6552  0.0  0.0  57680   936 ?        Ss   16:16   0:00 ssh -fNL 5433:localhost4:5433 cz
cpn       6554  0.0  0.0 103236   860 pts/0    S+   16:16   0:00 grep ssh
```

`pidof` returns all running ssh pids:

```
$ pidof ssh
6552 6098
```

I need to find the pid of the one with the reverse connection (`-nNCTR`).

Comment: have you tried `pgrep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give pgrep a go:

```
pgrep -f 'ssh .* -nNCTR'
```

Answer (score 1):

Netstat has the -p flag that can be used to display the pid of a connection.

```
netstat -alp | grep ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this

```
ps axu |grep 'nNCTR'
```

ps axu is great to grep from but there is one small problem!  The grep process itself!

```
ps axu |grep 'nNCTR' |grep -v grep
```

will exclude this too

Comment: Use `ps axu | grep '[n]NCTR'` to avoid the second grep. Better yet, use `pgrep`.